# Why my login panel has a wrong language?

Tags: wp-admin, login, localization

cleared cache and history and cookies. 
My browser is in English, 'WPLANG' is setted it_IT. 
I don't use third party themes, it's a totally custom theme, my own, coded line by line.
Latest WP on latest Firefox.

Still, for some obscure reason, my login has french texts (I want Italian or English).[image]

Any idea?

Comment: so do you have the french localization?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: do you actually have the french translation files? what language is your admin?

Comment: Mmmm the frontend (mytheme/languages/) has 5 languages, including french. My admin is Italian. But the login is wrongly french.

Comment: ok, so it is not totally out of place.... I would actually not know what should be the correct behaviour on the login page. Anyway this sounds like something that might be related to changes in localization done in 4.7, maybe the best thing is to open a trac ticket or try to contact ocean90 or pascal on the core slack